# should the workshop be able to use items in Conveyor storage and if not why is it using items in the conveyor storage?

Tags: fallout-4

I'm trying to tag for search some junk for a big project so I moved all my junk from the vault-tec workshop to a conveyor storage that happened to be nearby but then when I tried to tag for search again it said I had the same amount of Junk I always had, so what's going on is the workshop supposed to have access to the conveyor storage?

Comment: Keeping something in conveyor storage is roughly the same as keeping something inside of a trunk that you've built, with the one exception being that the conveyor system can interact with that particular bin. So no, it's not part of your _workshop_ storage.

Comment: What does "tag for search" mean?

Comment: tag for search is a feature of Fallout 4 where if you don't have enough junk for a build/mod you can press q in the workshop interface or t in the crafting menu and all the junk you need for that build will show up with a magnifying glass in inventories and containers containing what you need glow as well as lose junk with what you need

Comment: Ah, that is from the Workshop DLC? I have yet to play it with DLC (and mods).

Comment: @Joachim I'm pretty sure tag for search was in the base game. Not that I used it much, I generally just "take all" and dump it in the workshop anyway.